# How to take value from prompt and use that to change content to <li> element of todo app?

Tags: javascript, html, web

I was making  a todo app and i would like to edit the todo on click of a button with vanilla javascript . if i invoke a prompt on button click , how can i use the value to change the todo.

```
const edit = document.querySelector("#edt")
edit.onclick = function(){
    var text = prompt("Edi todo ");
    this.closest(".task").innerHTML
}
```

Full code:

```js
const input = document.querySelector("#add");
const btn = document.querySelector("#bttn");
const list = document.querySelector("#item");
var element = document.getElementsByTagName('li');

const edit = document.querySelector("#edt")
edit.onclick = function() {
  var text = prompt("Edi todo ");
  this.closest(".task").innerHTML
}

btn.onclick = function() {

  var txt = input.value;
  if (txt == '') {
    alert('Add some text');
  } else {
    li = document.createElement('li');
    li.classList.add("task");
    li.innerHTML = `<button id="edt" class="edit"><i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i></button>${txt}<button id="dlt" class="delete">X</button>`;
    list.insertBefore(li, list.childNodes[0]);
    input.value = '';
    addDeleteEvents();
  }

};

list.onclick = function(ev) {
  if (ev.target.tagName == 'LI') {
    ev.target.classList.toggle('checked');
  }
}

function addDeleteEvents() {
  var tasks = document.querySelectorAll(".task");
  for (var index = 0; index < tasks.length; index++) {
    tasks[index].addEventListener("click", function() {
      this.classList.toggle("active");
    });
    tasks[index].querySelector("#dlt").addEventListener("click",
      function() {
        this.closest(".task").remove();
      });
    //   tasks[index].querySelector("#edt").addEventListener("click",
    //   function(){

    //   });
  }
}

addDeleteEvents();

document.getElementById("add")
  .addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
      document.getElementById("bttn").click();
    }
  });
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins&display=swap');
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  outline: 0;
}

html {
  min-height: 100%;
}

body {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right bottom, #1857b7, #008ae1, #00b5cb, #00d782, #a8eb12);
}

.container {
  border-radius: 8px;
  box-shadow: #021025 0px 0px 15px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 460px;
  height: 690px;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right top, #d16ba5, #c777b9, #ba83ca, #aa8fd8, #9a9ae1, #8aa7ec, #79b3f4, #69bff8, #52cffe, #41dfff, #46eefa, #5ffbf1);
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.container::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

h1 {
  margin: 12px 0;
}

.add-todo {
  margin: 12px 0;
}

input {
  padding: 6px 4px;
  width: 70%;
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: #1857B7;
  background: #e6e1e1;
}

button {
  padding: 7px 14px;
  background-color: #00b0ff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: #fafafa;
}

#bttn {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #000102;
}

.list {
  height: 550px;
}

ul {
  padding: 15px;
  overflow: inherit;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 5px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background: rgba( 238, 24, 207, 0.55);
  box-shadow: 0 8px 32px 0 rgba( 31, 38, 135, 0.37);
  backdrop-filter: blur( 7.5px);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur( 7.5px);
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 1px solid rgba( 255, 255, 255, 0.18);
  margin: 12px 0;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .16);
  border-radius: 8px;
  transition: .4s;
}

button:hover {
  background-color: #1565c0;
}

li:hover {
  background: rgba(167, 9, 143, 0.787);
  box-shadow: 0 8px 32px 0 rgba( 31, 38, 135, 0.37);
  backdrop-filter: blur( 10.5px);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur( 10.5px);
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 1px solid rgba( 255, 255, 255, 0.18);
}

.delete {
  float: right;
  background: rgba( 2, 47, 68, 0.45);
  box-shadow: 0 8px 32px 0 rgba( 31, 38, 135, 0.37);
  backdrop-filter: blur( 10.5px);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur( 10.5px);
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 1px solid rgba( 255, 255, 255, 0.18);
}

.delete:hover {
  background: rgba( 226, 26, 86, 0.75);
  box-shadow: 0 8px 32px 0 rgba( 31, 38, 135, 0.37);
  backdrop-filter: blur( 10.5px);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur( 10.5px);
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 1px solid rgba( 255, 255, 255, 0.18);
}

.edit {
  float: left;
  background: rgba(14, 74, 102, 0.45);
  box-shadow: 0 8px 32px 0 rgba( 31, 38, 135, 0.37);
  backdrop-filter: blur( 10.5px);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur( 10.5px);
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 1px solid rgba( 255, 255, 255, 0.18);
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

.edit:hover {
  background: rgba(26, 226, 59, 0.75);
  box-shadow: 0 8px 32px 0 rgba( 31, 38, 135, 0.37);
  backdrop-filter: blur( 10.5px);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur( 10.5px);
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 1px solid rgba( 255, 255, 255, 0.18);
}

.bookmark {
  background: rgba( 255, 255, 255, 0.25);
  box-shadow: 0 8px 32px 0 rgba( 31, 38, 135, 0.37);
  backdrop-filter: blur( 4px);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur( 4px);
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  border: 1px solid rgba( 255, 255, 255, 0.18);
  position: absolute;
  top: 85%;
  padding-right: 3rem;
  padding-left: 1.5rem;
  z-index: 1;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  font-size: small;
}

.bookmark a {
  color: rgb(27, 23, 25);
}

.bookmark a:hover {
  color: #3800ee;
}

.checked {
  text-decoration: line-through;
  background: rgba(167, 9, 143, 0.787);
  box-shadow: 0 8px 32px 0 rgba( 31, 38, 135, 0.37);
  backdrop-filter: blur( 10.5px);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur( 10.5px);
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 1px solid rgba( 255, 255, 255, 0.18);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>To-Do</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/fvc.png" />

</head>

<body>
  <div class="bookmark">
    <h2>Made with ❤️ by <a href="https://aromalsanthosh.tech">Aromal</a></h2>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <h1>To-Do List</h1>

    <div class="add-todo">
      <input id="add" type="text" placeholder="Add A New Task..">
      <button id="bttn">Add</button>
    </div>
    <div class="list">
      <ul id="item">
        <li class="task"><button id="edt" class="edit"><i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i></button>Pay Electricity Bill <button id="dlt" class="delete">X</button></li>
        <li class="task"><button id="edt" class="edit"><i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i></button>Finish Todo App <button id="dlt" class="delete">X</button></li>

      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/e53b41c6e6.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: IDs need to be unique, you can't have multiple `id="edt"`. Use classes instead.

Comment: To change the contents of the LI, just assign `this.closest(".task").innerText = text`